# Debugger not taking me to current line number

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I am using `Visual Studio 2012` and when I debug my application then debug point is hitting but focus is not getting on to that point. I have to find that line to continue debugging. It is wasting my lot of time. Please suggest setting for getting over this weird behavior.

**Edit**

Let me elaborate little more. I have set debug point to page load and scrolled window to bottom of the window from where my debug line is not visible (obviously because I scrolled down) and I refresh the webpage. Then debug point is hit but I am on scrolled position (Normally debugger should have taken me to debug line).

**Edit**
I am not even able to navigating to definition when I hit <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: Please post the code which is failing to get hooked by the debugger, along with +/- say 5 lines.

Comment: are you debugging under Release build? If so your code might be optimized off, so that you cant debug certain lines.

Comment: @MarsonMao Code is debugging properly, just focus is not setting to that line. I mean I can debug but I have to find that line by scrolling window